# Error al guardar la ruta de una imagen en mi base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero guardar la ruta de una imagen en mi base de datos, estás imágenes se generan con html2canvas y se guardan en un directorio, pero cuando las genero y las guardo en mi base de datos se me genera un nombre de una imagen inexistente y ese es el que me almacena.

Este es el codigo de como se guarda la imagen en la base de datos:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include './save.php'; 
       
    $carpeta = './images';
    $ruta = $carpeta. "/". $imgName;

    $insertar = $conexion->query("INSERT INTO  images (img) VALUES ('$ruta')");
    
    if ($insertar) {
        echo "<script>alert('Imagen registrada exitosamente')</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo '<script>("Ups...Algo No va bien")</script>';
    }
}
```

Este es el código que me decodifica la imagen y me la guarda en la carpeta:

```php
    $image = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    

    $image = $image->captura;

    $image = str_replace("data:image/png;base64,", "", urldecode($image));
    $image = base64_decode($image); 

    $imgName = "Imagen_" . uniqid() . ".png";

    file_put_contents("images/$imgName", $image);
```